# Macro to save file if cells are filled

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save my file in a particular SharePoint folder when I press a button.

Within the same Excel spreadsheet I have data validation cells that should not be blank. If they are blank the macro should give me an error message and tell me that certain cells are blank and needs to be filled. If they are not blank, then save the file in the SharePoint folder.

My macro is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String

Path = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/"
FileName1 = Range("$B$2").Text
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & ".xlsx", _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

The cells are AD9:AM9 and AD10:AM10

Comment: Use `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.

Comment: You can add like ... `If isempty(Range("A1")) then `

Comment: `tells me that certain cells are blank` Which cells? Also avoid the use of `.Text`. Use `.Value` or `.Value2`

Comment: hi, Thanks for viewing but after I input the code after "" Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()""", it is giving me compile error. Any idea where should I add """ End if """ command after that?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, in this case, the cells that should't be blank are AD9:AM9 and AD10:AM10

Comment: sorry just saw this message. was busy playing catan :P glad it is sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `if` statement checks if cells are empty and proceeds to end the macro before saving if the range is empty. I merged your ranges as they are adjacent.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String


If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD9:AM10")) = 0  Then
        MsgBox "Data Validation Fields are empty"
        end ' stops the macro from running
Else

    Path = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/"
    FileName1 = Range("$B$2").Text
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & ".xlsx", _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End if

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow....it is working now!! Thank you so much Daghan for helping me out. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Now, if I want to add another data validation cell in this case, then can I add one more line with """"WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD10:AM10")) = 0"""" and then save the macro?

Comment: `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD9:AM10")) = 0 AND WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A10:A11")) = 0 Then`  Like this ,  with `And` both   statements must be true

Comment: But if you want `AD10:AM10` i already included it in the answer. Look at my description. My comment was if you wanted to add more cells to the data validation.

Comment: Wow, now it is working flawless. Thanks for your support. After spending a lot of time, the code works. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: That great :) Mark the question as answered.

Comment: Avoid the use of `.Text`. Use `.Value` or `.Value2`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event  like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, emptRng As Range
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
    Set rng = sh.Range("AD9:AM10")
     On Error Resume Next
      Set emptRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "There are empty cells in the range " & rng.Address & "." & vbCrLf & _
               "Please check, correct and save again after that..."
      End If
     On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, FaneDuru, Yeah but in this case, I want to save the file as a copy into my sharepoint folder after I click the macro button.

Comment: But, in such a case, instead of `Cancel = True` and `MsgBox` you can put there the `SaveAs` with your new path. Between `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`, to avoid triggering the event again...

Comment: hello FaneDuru, I am not very familiar with VBA but I will give it a try. thanks!